# Generating a PayPal payment link for a product and using it as a menu link

Tags: menu, hyperlink, payment

I hope to create an accordion menu that follows as a user moves down the page. I would create a separate menu with each item being a link item for a menu. Can I generate a simple link for an item that costs $39, another item that costs $79 and so forth? I am selling a small number of services and simply need to generate a link that goes to a specific item (one of 4-6 menu items, for example) at PayPal and allows for payment. I was trying to do something other than payment buttons becuase I want users to be able to make a purchase from nearly anywhere on my   site.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these 2 resources, they should be able to get you close to what you want.

1) https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/

2) http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Paypal-Payment-Link

Comment: What I was looking for was the link rather than the button (a button goes in one spot on one page. the link I would put in a menu item on my website. Thank you, however. I may dig into the HTML and get the link. I had thought of that. I had wondered if there were any "official" way to do it.

Comment: Ahh ok, check this question out then. It may be more of what you were looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879666/paypal-button-as-text-link

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestion. I had thought about the email option. My array of services will be small at first, perhaps only 4. So if build a special menu in Joomla, I can put these links into a floating menu that displays on every page. Much better than a button a customer must search for. Thanks for the suggestion. I had hoped that PayPal had anticipated this kind of possibility and there was actually a prescribed method.